# How to get properties from class Spring

Tags: spring

Is there a way to change

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file.properties" />
```

Into a java class with functions for every property? For example, being `file.properties`:

```
a=1
b=2
```

Write a class:

```
class Props {
    public A getA() {return 1;}
    public B getB() {return 2;}
}
```

Comment: Look at Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties`.